# Extracting lat/long of network vertices

Tags: qgis, point

I have created a point from the road network using vector>Geometry tools>extract Vertices tool. But after creating point from the line using this tech I have seen that the lat-long is the same. For example, I have a line from **A** to **B**; and A has a lat-long and B has a lat-long. By using extract Vertices tools let's suppose I have found 300 points but for every point, the lat-long is the same as **A** and **B** have. But I need individual lat-long for every point.
Is there any way I can do that in qgis?
point image:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to use the [geometry expressions in the field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=field%20calculator#geometry-functions) to add geometry values to the attribute table?

Comment: @Erik Kind of same. 
I have start and end lat-long for a line. I want to divide this line into like 50 parts, and every piece has to have the lat and long (start and end point).
In that case, which tools should I use? Or Can I use the tool you mentioned?

Comment: Did you even have a look at what I linked?

Comment: I have checked that but didn't get what I should use.

Comment: Please clarify which step you used after "extract vertices" in order to compute the vertice lat/lon values